# How to iterate over class components with Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm facing this problem and I already did some search about but I didn't find the answer.

What I wanna do?

I'm using retrofit to get some data from an API, I can get the data, but I wanna do a ForEach inside the class to find the property that I need.

```
    data class ChampionList(
            @SerializedName("version")
        val version : String,
        @SerializedName("data")
        val data : Data) <------ wanna do the foreach in this property
```

and I wanna do it, or something like this:  (Here I got the following error = for-loop range must have an 'iterator()' method)

```
      for(dataChampion in ChampionList.Data){
            //do something
    }
```

when I was searching, I found something about Kotlin reflection, but I didn't understand :(

another thing that I found but it didn't work was to use this:

```
 for(data in ChampionList::class.memberProperties){
   //access data here, but got an unresolved reference for member properties
}

classes:


    data class ChampionList(
        @SerializedName("version")
        val version : String,
        @SerializedName("data")
        val data : Data)



    data class Data (
        @SerializedName("Aatrox") val aatrox : Aatrox,
        @SerializedName("Ahri") val ahri : Ahri,
        @SerializedName("Akali") val akali : Akali,
        @SerializedName("Alistar") val alistar : Alistar,
        @SerializedName("Amumu") val amumu : Amumu,
        @SerializedName("Anivia") val anivia : Anivia
    }


    data class Aatrox(

        @SerializedName("version") val version: String,
        @SerializedName("id") val id: String,
        @SerializedName("key") val key: Int,
        @SerializedName("name") val name: String,
        @SerializedName("title") val title: String,
        @SerializedName("blurb") val blurb: String,
        @SerializedName("info") val info: Info,
        @SerializedName("image") val image: Image,
        @SerializedName("tags") val tags: List<String>,
        @SerializedName("partype") val partype: String,
        @SerializedName("stats") val stats: Stats
    )
```

all other classes like Ahri, Akali, Alistar, Amumu, and Anivia are the same that Aatrox

Answer (score 5):

```
for(data in ChampionList::class.memberProperties){
    //access data here, but got an unresolved reference for member properties
}
```

is the correct way (if you don't have any properties declared inside the class and don't care about the order), but you need to

1. Add the `kotlin-reflect` dependency as described [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#configuring-dependencies) (for Gradle) if you don't have it yet:

   ```
   implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect"
   ```
2. Add `import kotlin.reflect.full.memberProperties`;
3. If you do care about order or about not including properties inside the class, play with `ChampionList::class.primaryConstructor.valueParameters` instead.

Comment: sup man, i'm tring you solution but, for now i just can get the name of the parameters, but not the data(what i need)

what im trying to do:

  for (data in ChampionsList::class.memberProperties.iterator()){

                    Log.d("abacaxi", data.get(t).toString()) <-- here i can se the data, but how can i use it ?
                    Log.d("abacaxi", "test")

                }

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Calling methods on `data` such as `data.get(t)` _is_ how you use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
for (dataChampion in data.orEmpty()) { 
    //do something
 }
```

or this:

```
 data?.let {
    for (dataChampion in it) {

    }
}
```

My guess is that you're trying to iterate through a nullable type of data, hope this works for you. Best of luck on your League of Legends app :)

Comment: hey, I tried your solutions, but none worked :(  when i do the second solution, i got the follow error:  For-loop range must have an 'iterator()' method

Comment: now I realised what are you trying to do, it's because Data isn't really a list, can you clarify why you need to do this? what you want to achieve?

Comment: i wanna do a foreach inside the class Data(that has another classes as parameters(wanna get data inside this parameters))